# Exporting datagridview selectedrows to a datatable won't work

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I want to export all selectedRows from a datagridview to a DataTable. When clicking (selecting) on more than 2 rows, the next error appears:

"An exception error of type System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurred in System.Data.dll."

First, I tried:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_auswahlen.Rows.Count; i++) {
                if (dataGridView_auswahlen.Rows[i].Selected) {
                    table.Rows.Add( );
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView_auswahlen.Columns.Count; j++) {
                        table.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView_auswahlen[j, i].Value;
                    }
                }
            }
```

After that, I modified it in:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // create a table for storing selected rows
            var dtTemp = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable; // get the source table object
            dt = dtTemp.Clone();  // clone the schema of the source table to new table
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected)
                {
                  var row =   dt.NewRow();  // create a new row with the schema 
                  for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        row[j] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value;
                    }
                  dt.Rows.Add(row);  // add rows to the new table
                }
            }
```

The problem now, is that, my dataGridView is displaying only 1 result. I need to have the full result list in my dataGridView displayed and ONLY the selectedrows to be saved into a DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple code:

```
var dtSource = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
var dt = dtSource.Clone();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    dt.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows[row.Index]);
}
```

Comment: This saved me a ton of trouble.